# Entity Framework Migration Inheritance without creating the parent table

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-6

I have database objects that all inherit from a parent class with some base properties.

**Base Entity**

```
public abstract class Entity : IAuditable
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public int? CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public string UpdateBy { get; set; }
    public int? UpdatedDate { get; set; }
}
```

**Base Entity Configuration file**

```
public EntityConfiguration()
{
    HasKey(e => e.Id);

    Property(e => e.Id)
        .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);

    Property(e => e.CreatedBy)
        .IsUnicode(false)
        .HasMaxLength(255);

    Property(e => e.UpdatedBy)
        .IsUnicode(false)
        .HasMaxLength(255);
}
```

I subclass entity on all the child classes to inherit the common properties

```
public class User : Entity
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

**DbContext**

```
public class SomeContext : DbContext
{
    public SomeContext() : base("name=DefaultConnection")
    {
    }

    public static SomeContext Create()
    {
        return new SomeContext();
    }

    public DbSet<Collaboration> Users { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new EntityConfiguration());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new UserConfiguration());
    }
}
```

When I create the migrations It will create all the inherited properties correctly but it still creates the parent class (Entity) even though I don't have a DbSet. If I remove the line that adds the configuration settings in the OnModelCreating method I don't get the max lengths and Unicode settings.

Is there a way to use the configuration properties without actually creating the parent table and without adding the configurations to all the subclass configuration files.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If anyone is interested here are the two solutions that I came up with. I opted for the second one as it seems to be the more accurate solution.

**Solution 1**

Use the Types configuration to the base class and anything inheriting the base class will also inherit the configuration.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Types<Entity>().Configure(c =>
    {
        c.HasKey(e => e.Id);

        c.Property(e => e.Id)
            .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);

        c.Property(e => e.CreatedBy)
            .IsUnicode(false)
            .HasMaxLength(255);

        c.Property(e => e.UpdatedBy)
            .IsUnicode(false)
            .HasMaxLength(255);
    });

    modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new UserConfiguration());
}
```

**Solution 2**

Use a combination of Generics, Interfaces and Inheritance to create a base EntityTypeConfiguration class. Then have other entity type configurations classes inherit from it.

```
public interface IEntity
{
    int Id { get; set; }
}

public interface IAuditable
{
    string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    DateTime? CreatedDate { get; set; }
    string UpdatedBy { get; set; }
    DateTime? UpdatedDate { get; set; }
}

public class EntityConfiguration<T> : EntityTypeConfiguration<T> where T : class, IEntity, IAuditable
{
    public EntityConfiguration()
    {
        HasKey(e => e.Id);

        Property(e => e.Id)
            .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);

        Property(e => e.CreatedBy)
            .IsUnicode(false)
            .HasMaxLength(255);

        Property(e => e.UpdatedBy)
            .IsUnicode(false)
            .HasMaxLength(255);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This approach of inheritance with EF Code first is the [Table per Concrete Type TPC Hierarchy](https://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-3-table-per-concrete-type-tpc-and-choosing-strategy-guidelines)

In the link you can find all the logic with examples on how to implement it. I know I shouldn't provide links but check the link, it has everything :)

Examples, Code explanation, graphs and images. I think it is exactly what you need to understand the TPC.

Comment: I did run into this link but it doesn't how me to make the changes in the EntityConfiguration class. I ended up using modelBuilder.Types<Entity>().Configure(c => {}) to fix my issue. I will post the answer as soon as the two day grace period is over.

Answer (score -1):

**First remove your `Base EntityConfiguration` class as  you don't want to generate database table for it**

**Solution-1: *Using Data Annotation***

*Your `Base Entity` class should be as follows:*

```
public abstract class Entity
{
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [MaxLength(255)]
        [Column(TypeName = "Varchar")]
        public string CreatedBy { get; set; }

        public DateTime? CreatedDate { get; set; }

        [MaxLength(255)]
        [Column(TypeName = "Varchar")]
        public string UpdateBy { get; set; }

        public DateTime? UpdatedDate { get; set; }
 }
```

*and then your `DbContext` should be as follows:*

```
public class SomeContext : DbContext
{
    public SomeContext() : base("name=DefaultConnection")
    {
    }

    public static SomeContext Create()
    {
        return new SomeContext();
    }

    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new UserConfiguration());
    }

}
```

**Solution-2: *Using Fluent API***

Your *`Base Entity`* configuration in the `DbContext` should be as follows:

```
public class SomeContext : DbContext
{
    public SomeContext() : base("name=DefaultConnection")
    {
    }

    public static SomeContext Create()
    {
        return new SomeContext();
    }

    public DbSet<Collaboration> Users { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
       modelBuilder.Types<Entity>().Configure(c =>
        {
            c.HasKey(e => e.Id);

            c.Property(e => e.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);

            c.Property(e => e.CreatedBy)
                .IsUnicode(false)
                .HasMaxLength(255);

            c.Property(e => e.UpdateBy)
                .IsUnicode(false)
                .HasMaxLength(255);
        });
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new UserConfiguration());
    }
}
```

**On both cases Migration will generate `Users` Table as follows:**

```
public override void Up()
{
            CreateTable(
                "dbo.Users",
                c => new
                    {
                        Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                        FirstName = c.String(),
                        LastName = c.String(),
                        CreatedBy = c.String(maxLength: 255, unicode: false),
                        CreatedDate = c.DateTime(),
                        UpdateBy = c.String(maxLength: 255, unicode: false),
                        UpdatedDate = c.DateTime(),
                    })
                .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id);

  }
```

**Hope your problem will be solved!**

Comment: I did try this previously. Although it will give me the inherited fiels, I lose the custom field properties such as max length and Unicode that are in the EntityTypeConfiguration class. I do come up with a solution which I will post when the two day grace period is over

Comment: @Dblock247 Why would you lose custom field properties? Okay let me check again.

Comment: because you are removing modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new EntityConfiguration()) from OnModelConfiguration. That class contains all the configuration info. Also the point is not to add configuration to each child entity. I want it to inherit everything from the parent

Comment: but I am using `UserCofiguration`..Please read my answer thoroughly..No problem I am checking it with a new project.

Comment: Yes I know but if i was going to do that. I dont need inheritance. I would have to add that to every child entity configuration

Comment: Yes! You have to do every child configuration as you are not generating the base entity class table. but what's wrong to do that? Moreover why you don't need inheritance? then how will you get the common properties?

Comment: actually I found one way around it that works and I am testing another now.

Comment: Please check my answer now! I have updated my answer right now which will give you what you exactly wanted! cheers!

Comment: I really thank you for your help but as I have said I have figure it out and have two different solution. I would accept your answer but it involves data annotations. As I stated previously my answer invoices modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new EntityConfiguration()). The answer that I decided to use was to create a Base class for EntityTypeConfiguration and use both inheritance and generics with constraints to accomplish my goal. Thank you again for your time and effort.

Comment: Dear, This is not good practice to write fluent API and configuration class when you have Data Annotations support. Data Annotation makes code more cleaner and readable. Write fluent API and configuration class only when you don't have data annotation support. When you have the best solution then why would you prefer you own solution?. Good bye! Thank you for long discussion.

Comment: I prefer fluent api. I like to keep my pocos clean. Your welcome